# Forward WhatsApp messages to e-mail or SMS

Tags: sms, whatsapp-messenger, email

Some friends of mine want to use WhatsApp to send me messages from time to time. But, I don't want to install the app (or I don't want to have it running all the time). Can I configure something within WhatsApp or another service to forward the messages from WhatsApp to an e-mail address via SMS?

Even a solution that requires me to configure a program on my own server would suffice.

Comment: Whatsapp uses encryption plus proprietary methods which do not allow apps / services to interact with its internals. They're is no such configuration in app - guess that's s dead end

Comment: i personally would ignore people who are such ignorant that they won't respect your decision not to use whatsapp and/or too stupid for sending you email instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can bridge WhatsApp to Matrix using mautrix which can be bridged to other serives like email. It is unfortunatley quite the hacky setup:

1. Have a [Synapse](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse) or another Matrix server
2. [Run an Android VM to run WhatsApp](https://github.com/tulir/mautrix-whatsapp/wiki/Android-VM-Setup)
3. [Run the mautrix bridge](https://github.com/tulir/mautrix-whatsapp/wiki/Bridge-setup)
4. Run another bridge, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/kamax-matrix/matrix-appservice-email), to bridge to email or wherever desired.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution available. But you can install whatsapp and turn off notification - from app settings.

If you want to use whatsapp like email on pc. Try using whatsapp web.

https://web.whatsapp.com

Comment: Please let me know if it helps

Comment: I guess you don't want disturbance due to whatsapp messages coming evey now and then or may be you prefer working from your pc